# How to map a table to a context using fluent API?

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, fluent

I present to you my situation: I have 2 tables, for example, orders lists and customers; to each order is associated with a customer, the orders table belongs to "MyDepot" database and the customers table belongs to "Main" database.

I've create 2 different contexts, MyDepotContext and MainContext.
How do I map the orders and not customers to the MyDepotContext ?
An how do I map customers and not orders to the MainContext ?

Is it possible by using Fluent API ?

Edited :
I'm using SQL Server on Azure, so i cannot use the "Linked Servers" functionnality since it's only implemented for Managed Azure SQL Database.

Comment: What database engine?  Can you use cross-database queries, or cross-database views or synonyms?

Comment: I've edited my question, we are using SQL Server on Azure. I've tried to setup "Linked Server" but it's only available in managed SQL Server Database. I've also successfully setup an external table following this documentation [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/384520cf4e124ef9d6f8dcff8ed4200d4d2e1f9d/articles/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-getting-started-vertical.md), but this is read only, the data can't be modified this way :(

Comment: I thought about an other solution, rather than modifing the application code, I'll thought about doing it from the database point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An EF DbContext is bound to a single Database Connection.  If you have multiple databases and can't use cross-database queries you'll have to have multiple DbContext types and manage any cross-context operations on the client.

Comment: Maybe someone has an idea how to do the "manage any cross-context operations on the client" of your answer ? Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: You would simply define a DTO that has entities from both contexts.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware about DTO term. I'll be looking for this technique. Is it related to AutoMapper ? Or maybe someone has a ressource/link/docs to share.